# How to implement a class with a static self-increase member in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to implement a class using Scala like this:

```
class Ref(name: String, size: Int)
```

if I want to add a static member in this class I need add a componion object:

```
object Ref {
  private var id: Int = 0
}
```

Then, when I create an object such as val ref = new Ref("something", 20), How should I do to let the member "id" could self-increase (like id = id + 1)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963080/static-field-in-scala-companion-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AtomicInteger` to avoid concurrent bug with incrementing `id` value.

```
object Ref {
  private val id = new AtomicInteger()

  def next = id.incrementAndGet()
}

class Ref(name: String, size: Int) {
  val id = Ref.next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the counter inside the primary constructor

```
object Ref {
  var id: Int = 0
}

class Ref {
   Ref.id = Ref.id + 1 
}
```